# When we Shipped Quote into Dynamics GP From Dynamics CRM Which field changed

Tags: dynamics-gp

I want to get quotes that are shipped from Dynamics CRM to Dynamics GP. But I have only database access to get quotes. How can I get these quotes.

If anyone have an idea please share with me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying you want to integrate a quote from Dynamics GP into Dynamics CRM. Or do you have an opportunity in Dynamics CRM that you would like to integrate into Dynamics GP as a quote?

Answer (score 0):

When a new quote is created in Dynamics GP, a new header record for the quote should be created in the SOP10100 table in that company's database.  Try adding a trigger on the SOP10100 table, and look at the SOPTYPE (integer) value - a value of 1 means it's a quote.  [In case it matters to you now or later: 1 = Quote, 2 = Order, 3 = Invoice, 4 = Return, and 5 = Backorder.]

Any line items for the quote will be in the SOP10200 table, and you can link the two tables using a combination of SOPTYPE and SOPNUMBE (the document number) - note that document numbers are only unique for a given SOP (Sales Order Processing) document type, so be sure to link the tables using both fields.

Other information related to the quote will be stored in other SOP (and maybe non-SOP) tables.  Start by reviewing Victoria Yudin's excellent guide to the SOP tables at http://victoriayudin.com/gp-tables/sop-tables/.  You can get more details about any given table from gptablereference.com, e.g. http://www.gptablereference.com/2010/Table/SOP10100.